# Adaptec SCSI Card 39160. What to do with it?

Tags: scsi, adaptec

Almost 10 years ago I bough an Adaptec SCSI Card 39160 for two Hitachi hard disks, with 80/68 pins adapters and cables and all the accoutrements.

The hard disks died after 2 years (so much for reliability), I eventually realized that SCSI was overkill and stowed it away for "future use" like a bonafide nerd pack rat.

I found it again 3 days ago during my hardware Summer cleaning. Tried it, still works.

I've been out of the server/networking loop for years now, so I don't know what's still relevant and what's not. Apparently Adaptec still sells it, but I tried to sell it on eBay, and, seriously, just 11 people even looked at it.

So, my question is simple: Is this card a hardware coprolite which can safely be thrown away, or would that be a sacrilege of some sort? Is this card still relevant or useful in any way?

Comment: Bin it, it's worthless. Oh and read our FAQ please, this question wasn't appropriate for this site.

Comment: 10x. And sorry. :)

Answer (score 2):

Throw it away.

SCSI is legacy - got long replaced with SAS / SATA (you can use SATA drives in a SAS enclosure) which is easier to deal with and provides a lot higher perofrmacne and can handle al ot more drives.

What to do with it depends on your living circumstances ;) Throw it away, donate it, put it under glass on the wall in your workroom ;) But using it is not worth it anymore.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this. I suspected that SCSI might have been become legacy, but couldn't find a definitive answer. I'm throwing it away, with a bleeding heart. :)